# rtlwifi_new-master error

Tags: 14.04, wireless, gnome-terminal

While I'm using the command 'make' in the directory, I get the following error,

```
  root@sahil:~/Desktop/Untitled Folder/rtlwifi_new-master# cd 
rtlwifi_new-master
    bash: cd: rtlwifi_new-master: No such file or directory
    root@sahil:~/Desktop/Untitled Folder/rtlwifi_new-master# make
    make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-34-generic/build M=/home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled Folder/rtlwifi_new-master modules
    make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic'
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    /bin/sh: 1: cannot create /home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk: Directory nonexistent
    make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Folder/rtlwifi_new-master'.  Stop.
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-34-generic'
    Makefile:58: recipe for target 'all' failed
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    root@sahil:~/Desktop/Untitled Folder/rtlwifi_new-master#
```

I don't know how to fix it and I'm looking for help.

Comment: Wow! It worked but why it showed error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From Comments**: Renaming the folder `Untitled Folder` to  another name without ***space*** like `Untitled_folder` helps. `make` command tried to create a folder `/home/sahil/Desktop/Untitled/.cache.mk` but since folder named as `Untitled` doesn't exists thus it can't create `.cache.mk` folder. This resulted in the error.

While `make` is executed inside a folder it takes the path as a whole. But since path contained 'spaces' so it copied the path before the space and consider it as the new path. Also, it considered what was after space as some parameter which caused another error `make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'Folder/rtlwifi_new-master'.  Stop`.

There's  a good [explanation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148044/303673) by [Celeda](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/14034/celada) in the question [Is space not allowed in a filename?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/148043/is-space-not-allowed-in-a-filename) on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/):

> *The recommendation to not use spaces in filenames comes from the danger that they might be misinterpreted by software that poorly supports them. Arguably, such software is buggy. But also arguably, programming languages like shell scripting make it all too easy to write software that breaks when presented with filenames with spaces in them, and these bugs tend to slip through because shell scripts are not often tested by their developers using filenames with spaces in them*